# Steps to deploy a model-first EF app

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, deployment, ef-model-first

Now that my EF app (app which accesses MS SQL server 2008 Express using EF 5 Model-first approach) is working on my development machine, I need to deploy (or install) it on a deployment machine.

What are the steps involved in setting up the deployment machine in order for my app to work correctly?

[I was thinking:

  1. Install MSSQL 2008 express on deployment m/c

  2. Execute the app.edmx.sql in SSMS to create the database and tables

  3. copy my app binaries to deployment m/c

  4. change the data Source in the connection string in the edmx file and start the app

not sure whether this will work or not.]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the steps I mentioned in my question, worked !

Here's the steps:

1. Install MSSQL 2008 express on deployment m/c
2. Execute the app.edmx.sql in SSMS to create the database and tables
3. copy app binaries to deployment m/c
4. change the data Source in the connection string in the edmx file to match to the server name (for me it was the machine name) and start the app